# Not able to access the classes's variable from within the function of the class in the particular case

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I didn't know how to best explain the question since there are a lot of things going, so I went ahead and created a sample of what I'm doing. Below is the code:

```
var cl = new Class();
cl.handleAction("triggerScream");
cl.handleAction('triggerDisplay');



function Class()
{
  //function which will print static string
  this.scream = function(){
    document.write("AAAAAAA!!!<br/>");
  }
  
    
  //function which will print the class variable
  this.display = function(){
    document.write( this.color );
  };
  
  
  //sample class variable
  this.color = 'red';
  
  
  //map of actions
  this.actions = {
    'triggerDisplay' : this.display,
    'triggerScream' : this.scream
  };
  
  
  //generic function that handles all actions
  this.handleAction = function(action){
    try{
      this.actions[action]();
    }catch(err)
    {
      document.write("Error doing "+action);
    }
  };
}
```

And here's the jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/etimer/2/edit

In the summary, there's a `handleAction()` function, which handles various events and evokes other functions to complete the event. For that I have the map of action events and functions to evoke. Function `display()` of the class accesses the class variable, but for some reason `this` is undefined inside of that function. Any ideas of why and how to fix it so that I can access the variable and preferably keeping the code architecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope when you call the function function is different from the scope of the Class object. That means "this" referrs to something else:

```
function Class()
{
  //function which will print static string
  this.scream = function(){
    document.write("AAAAAAA!!!<br/>");
  }


  //function which will print the class variable
  this.display = function(){
    document.write( this.color );
  };

  //sample class variable
  this.color = 'red';



 //generic function that handles all actions
     this.handleAction = function(action){
    try{
      //you are calling the function in another scope
      this.actions[action]();
    }catch(err)
    {
      document.write("Error doing "+action);
    }
  };
}
```

Instead you can do:

```
function Class()
{
  //function which will print static string
  this.scream = function(){
    document.write("AAAAAAA!!!<br/>");
  }


  //function which will print the class variable
  this.display = function(){
    document.write(color);
  };


  //sample class variable
  //this way it's available to all inside functions
  var color = 'red';
}
```

This is not an easy chapter though but I recommend you learn more about javascript scopes and clojures.

Basically what you need to learn from here is that when you call a function without any prior context it cannot rely on "this". That's why the context can be changed for the method invokation using `.call(context,args..)`

Example:

```
function Class()
{
  //we store the context
  var scope=this;
  //function which will print static string
  this.scream = function(){
    document.write("AAAAAAA!!!<br/>");
  }


  //function which will print the class variable
  this.display = function(){
    document.write(this.color);
  };


  //sample class variable
  this.color = 'red';


  //map of actions
  this.actions = {
    'triggerDisplay' : this.display,
    'triggerScream' : this.scream
  };


  //generic function that handles all actions
  this.handleAction = function(action){
    try{
      //we call our function in the Class context
      this.actions[action].call(scope);
    }catch(err)
    {
      document.write("Error doing "+action);
    }
 };
}
var cl = new Class();
cl.handleAction("triggerScream");
cl.handleAction("triggerDisplay");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was guessing the cause of the issue. It was difficult to keep track of scopes because of a lot of re-assignations of the function. I will try this solutions. Thanks!